# Should I accept my coworker's offer of food as penance for arriving late?

Tags: colleagues, commute

I started carpooling with my coworker this week; he drives and picks me up from a main road near my house. Yesterday, he arrived 5 minutes late. Today, he misread the time and did not leave his house until 10 minutes after he was supposed to arrive. Luckily I had access to an alternate means of transportation and was only 10 minutes later than normal, and our company is flexible about arrival times.

Nevertheless, my coworker seems distraught about these events. Our department regularly goes out to eat together, and he has offered to pay for my food the next time we go to make it up to me. Should I accept this offer?

Comment: Are you asking whether you should accept the apology, or whether you should accept the food at all? Either way, it's really up to you.

Comment: @DavidK The food, obviously. I'm not too bothered by his tardiness.

Comment: Accepting or declining could possibly both be considered rude depending on culture. What country are you in?

Comment: @Dukeling Canada.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this seems quite normal. He wants to make it up to you.
Now if he continues to be late often, you might want to reconsider how you travel and avoid uncomfortable moments for both.